# Deep Copying Structs

Tags: c, caching, struct, deep-copy

I have reviewed the example on Stack Overflow about Deep Copying struct but those examples didn't work for my case. I have trying to simulate a simple Cache were the user can change the set number and lines per set. However, when setting up the sets I realized each line pointed to the same thing and as a result when you change Line 0 in Set 0 it also changes Line 0 in Set 1. Any advice on how to make the sets not have the same lines or better method to set up the Cache structure?

```
typedef struct Line {
    unsigned int valid;
    unsigned int tag;
    unsigned int lru;
}Line;

typedef struct Set {
    Line lines[0];
}Set;

Set *MakeSet(int n) {
    Set *s;
    s = malloc(sizeof s->lines *n);

    return s;
}

typedef struct Cahce {
    Set sets[0];
}Cache;

Cache *MakeCache(int n){
    Cache *c;
    c = malloc(sizeof c->sets *n);

    return c;
}

int main(void) {

int lines_per_set =1;
int num_sets = 2;

Set *s = MakeSet(lines_per_set);

    Line generic_line;
    generic_line.valid = 0;
    generic_line.tag =0;
    generic_line.lru =0;

    for(int i=0; i<lines_per_set; i++){
        s->lines[i] = generic_line;
    }

    Cache *c = MakeCache(num_sets);

    for(int j=0; j<num_sets; j++){
        c->sets[j] = *s;
    }

  c->sets[0].lines[0].valid =1;
  printf("%d", c->sets[1].lines[0].valid );

return 0;
}
```

Comment: C does not support arrays with dimension 0.  If your compiler accepts that as an extension then it does not mean what you probably think it means.

Comment: In particular, `sizeof s->lines` and `sizeof c->sets` do not mean what you appear to think they mean.  Also, you are going to run into issues with `struct Set` and `struct Cahce` [sic] not representing how many lines and sets, respectively, they contain.

Comment: read about [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member)s

Comment: And among the things you need to know about flexible array members is that their contents are not copied by the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most H/W, the number of *sets per cache* and *lines per set* is fixed.

But, your example mixes up fixed/variable a bit. So, it isn't clear [to me] what level of sophistication you want.

Note, in the examples below, there *isn't* a function that *duplicates*. Just does initial creation. That's the first step. The code below should give you some ideas on how to proceed.

---

Here's a refactored example with all parameters fixed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum {
    LINES_PER_SET = 1,
    NUM_SETS = 2
};

typedef struct {
    unsigned int valid;
    unsigned int tag;
    unsigned int lru;
} Line;

typedef struct {
    int set_linecount;
    Line set_lines[LINES_PER_SET];
} Set;

typedef struct {
    int cache_setcount;
    Set cache_sets[NUM_SETS];
} Cache;

Cache *
MakeCache(void)
{
    Cache *c;

    c = calloc(1,sizeof(Cache));

    return c;
}

int
main(void)
{

    Cache *c = MakeCache();

    c->cache_sets[0].set_lines[0].valid = 1;
    printf("%d\n", c->cache_sets[0].set_lines[0].valid);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a refactored example that allows the set count and line count to be defined dynamically:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int valid;
    unsigned int tag;
    unsigned int lru;
} Line;

typedef struct {
    int set_linecount;
    Line *set_lines;
} Set;

typedef struct {
    int cache_setcount;
    Set *cache_sets;
} Cache;

Line *
MakeLine(Line *line)
{

    if (line == NULL)
        line = malloc(sizeof(Line));

    line->valid = 0;
    line->tag = 0;
    line->lru = 0;

    return line;
}

Set *
MakeSet(Set *s,int nline)
{
    Line *line;

    if (s == NULL)
        s = malloc(sizeof(Set));

    s->set_linecount = nline;
    s->set_lines = malloc(sizeof(Line) * nline);

    for (int lineidx = 0;  lineidx < s->set_linecount;  ++lineidx) {
        line = &s->set_lines[lineidx];
        MakeLine(line);
    }

    return s;
}

Cache *
MakeCache(Cache *c,int nset,int nline)
{
    Set *s;

    if (c == NULL)
        c = malloc(sizeof(Cache));

    c->cache_setcount = nset;
    c->cache_sets = calloc(nset,sizeof(Set));

    for (int setidx = 0;  setidx < c->cache_setcount;  ++setidx) {
        s = &c->cache_sets[setidx];
        MakeSet(s,nline);
    }

    return c;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int lines_per_set = 1;
    int num_sets = 2;

    Cache *c = MakeCache(NULL,num_sets,lines_per_set);

    c->cache_sets[0].set_lines[0].valid = 1;
    printf("%d\n", c->cache_sets[0].set_lines[0].valid);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's a third example that uses an extra level of indirection:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned int valid;
    unsigned int tag;
    unsigned int lru;
} Line;

typedef struct {
    int set_linecount;
    Line **set_lines;
} Set;

typedef struct {
    int cache_setcount;
    Set **cache_sets;
} Cache;

Line *
MakeLine(void)
{
    Line *line;

    line = malloc(sizeof(Line));

    line->valid = 0;
    line->tag = 0;
    line->lru = 0;

    return line;
}

Set *
MakeSet(int nline)
{
    Line *line;
    Set *s;

    s = malloc(sizeof(Set));

    s->set_linecount = nline;
    s->set_lines = malloc(sizeof(Line *) * nline);

    for (int lineidx = 0;  lineidx < s->set_linecount;  ++lineidx)
        s->set_lines[lineidx] = MakeLine();

    return s;
}

Cache *
MakeCache(int nset,int nline)
{
    Cache *c;

    c = malloc(sizeof(Cache));

    c->cache_setcount = nset;
    c->cache_sets = calloc(nset,sizeof(Set *));

    for (int setidx = 0;  setidx < c->cache_setcount;  ++setidx)
        c->cache_sets[setidx] = MakeSet(nline);

    return c;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int lines_per_set = 1;
    int num_sets = 2;

    Cache *c = MakeCache(num_sets,lines_per_set);

    c->cache_sets[0]->set_lines[0]->valid = 1;
    printf("%d\n", c->cache_sets[0]->set_lines[0]->valid);

    return 0;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Thank you for the explanation. I liked the second one the best. How would you free the allocated memory? I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num_sets; i++) {
   for (int j = 0; j < lines_per_set; j++)
       free(c->sets[i].lines[j]);
}
free(c);
```

> But is says that the elements in lines are not the right type. I thought they were pointers.

Although it is possible to free things all at once, it's better to use a few subfunctions to do the job. Just like `Make*` functions, we could create `Free*` functions.

A good maxim might be: *If a function [or statement] "seems" overly complex or error prone, it might need to be split up into smaller functions.*

In fact, in the example below, I cannibalized the `Make*` functions to create the `Free*` functions.

In the original `Make*` functions, the function was passed a pointer to the struct it was creating/initializing. If that pointer was `NULL`, it was doing a `malloc`. Thus, it "knows" whether it's doing the `malloc` or not.

That allowed the function to either create a "free standing" struct with `malloc` [as `MakeCache` did] or have the struct be a subordinate of another struct (e.g. `Set` was subordinate to `Cache` and `Line` was subordinate to `Set`). This may not be the most optimal way to do it [a seperate "alloc" and "init" function might be cleaner].

However, for a `Free*` function, the *caller* would have to "tell" the function whether to do a `free` of the struct pointer or not. This would be messy as the caller would have to keep track of [such] things. Usually, keeping track of that is the province of the individual functions.

So, I've added an extra member to each struct that "remembers" whether the struct was allocated or not. Then, the `Free*` function can look at that to determine whether it can free its pointer or not. This is a personal "trick of the trade" that I've used a lot in production code. This field could just be an boolean `int` (as in `cache_alloced`). But, I chose to use a bit mask with various option bits (e.g. `OPT_ALLOC`). This is to allow for future expansion if needed.

I've created a few helper CPP macros to assist in this [be careful what you wish for, you might actually get it :-)].

You may notice that the various `FREEME*` macros first check if the "about to be freed" pointer is `NULL`, and suppress the call to `free` if so. This isn't really necessary because it *is* permissible to call `free` with a null pointer [i.e. it is harmless].

Another thing they do is, after the `free`, they set the pointer to `NULL`. This is a "safety" feature to catch misuse/reuse of a "freed" pointer. It also prevents a "double free" abort from `free` (e.g. `free(ptr); free(ptr);` would cause this).

If the pointer is *not* nulled, the dereference *might* succeed with undefined results. That is UB [undefined behavior] but might be hard to detect. By zeroing out the pointer, any subsequent dereference of the pointer would trigger an immediate `SIGSEGV` [segfault].

*Side note:* I followed your convention for naming functions. And, although I didn't do it herein, I've found it useful to reverse the "object" and "verb". That is, instead of (e.g.) `MakeCache` and `FreeCache`, I'd do: `CacheMake` and `CacheFree`. That way, if there were more functions that operated on a given struct pointer, they would "line up" if we produced a sorted list of *all* functions.

Anyway, here's how I would do the freeing of the structs:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef unsigned int u32;

#define OPT_ALLOC       (1u << 0)           // 1=struct has been malloc'ed

#define ALLOCME(_ptr) \
    _ptr = malloc(sizeof(*_ptr))

#define ALLOCMEIF(_ptr,_opt) \
    do { \
        if (_ptr != NULL) { \
            _ptr->_opt = 0; \
            break; \
        } \
        ALLOCME(_ptr); \
        _ptr->_opt = OPT_ALLOC; \
    } while (0)

#define FREEME(_ptr) \
    do { \
        if (_ptr == NULL) \
            break; \
        free(_ptr); \
        _ptr = NULL; \
    } while (0)

#define FREEMEIF(_ptr,_opt) \
    do { \
        if (_ptr == NULL) \
            break; \
        if (_ptr->_opt & OPT_ALLOC) { \
            free(_ptr); \
            _ptr = NULL; \
        } \
    } while (0)

typedef struct {
    u32 line_opt;
    u32 valid;
    u32 tag;
    u32 lru;
} Line;

typedef struct {
    u32 set_opt;
    int set_linecount;
    Line *set_lines;
} Set;

typedef struct {
    u32 cache_opt;
    int cache_setcount;
    Set *cache_sets;
} Cache;

Line *
MakeLine(Line *line)
{

    ALLOCMEIF(line,line_opt);

    line->valid = 0;
    line->tag = 0;
    line->lru = 0;

    return line;
}

Set *
MakeSet(Set *s,int nline)
{
    Line *line;

    ALLOCMEIF(s,set_opt);

    s->set_linecount = nline;
    s->set_lines = malloc(sizeof(Line) * nline);

    for (int lineidx = 0;  lineidx < s->set_linecount;  ++lineidx) {
        line = &s->set_lines[lineidx];
        MakeLine(line);
    }

    return s;
}

Cache *
MakeCache(Cache *c,int nset,int nline)
{
    Set *s;

    ALLOCMEIF(c,cache_opt);

    c->cache_setcount = nset;
    c->cache_sets = calloc(nset,sizeof(Set));

    for (int setidx = 0;  setidx < c->cache_setcount;  ++setidx) {
        s = &c->cache_sets[setidx];
        MakeSet(s,nline);
    }

    return c;
}

Line *
FreeLine(Line *line)
{

    FREEMEIF(line,line_opt);

    return line;
}

Set *
FreeSet(Set *s)
{
    Line *line;

    for (int lineidx = 0;  lineidx < s->set_linecount;  ++lineidx) {
        line = &s->set_lines[lineidx];
        FreeLine(line);
    }

    FREEME(s->set_lines);
    FREEMEIF(s,set_opt);

    return s;
}

Cache *
FreeCache(Cache *c)
{
    Set *s;

    for (int setidx = 0;  setidx < c->cache_setcount;  ++setidx) {
        s = &c->cache_sets[setidx];
        FreeSet(s);
    }

    FREEME(c->cache_sets);
    FREEMEIF(c,cache_opt);

    return c;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int lines_per_set = 1;
    int num_sets = 2;

    Cache *c = MakeCache(NULL,num_sets,lines_per_set);

    c->cache_sets[0].set_lines[0].valid = 1;
    printf("%d\n", c->cache_sets[0].set_lines[0].valid);

    c = FreeCache(c);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . This is very helpful.